# Web Api built with msbuild does not work due to Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native assemblies

Tags: asp.net-web-api, msbuild, command-line-interface, roslyn

I recently started running into an issue when building my web api project using MSBuild on VSTS and I managed to reproduce it locally.

My Web Api is a standard, run of the mill api with nothing fancy added.
It has the following packages installed:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Autofac.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Autofac.WebApi2.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Kentico.Libraries" version="10.0.16" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Kentico.Libraries.Dependencies" version="10.0.16" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="PagedList" version="1.17.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Dynamic" version="1.0.7" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

When I build the project locally using Visual Studio 2015, the API works as expected. 
However, when I build the project using msbuild:

```
msbuild Portal.WebApi.csproj /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration="Nightly" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:OutputPath="C:\Temp\BuildOutput"
```

and point my IIS to the the _PublishedWebsites\Portal.WebApi\ folder, it fails with the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

If I remove Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform and Microsoft.Net.Compilers packages from the API project and build it again using MSBuild, the API works again as expected.

If I compare the bin folders (Visual studio build vs MSBuild), the msbuild bin folder has additional dlls and all the content of the roslyn folder is added directly to the bin folder.

Has anyone encountered such an issue?

Comment: the roslyn folder in \bin is how Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform works. CodeDom needs to be able to compile your .cshtml views at runtime, hence the additional folder